# Regular expression that matches only the root of an relative path

Tags: regex, relative-path

im a newbie with RegEx and i cant figure out how to create an regular expression that matches only the data at the root of an relative path.

the regex should match everything at the root. examples:

```
\info.txt 
\.htaccess
\log
\武警支队.txt
```

but should not match any data from deeper sub-folders like:

```
\data\db.txt
\pics\main\info.jpg
\Всеобщая\การเข้าถึงถูกปฏิเสธ\ใหม่.rtf
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `^\\[^\\]+$`.

`[^\\]` means anything other than `\`.

Comment: http://regexr.com/ Is a great tool for learning regExp. I put your best answer as a project there. 

http://regexr.com/3ght7